# Use of DeepExplainer to get shap values for an MLP model in Keras with tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, shap

I am playing around with DeepExplainer to get shap values for deep learning models. By following some tutorials I can get some results, i.e. what variables are pushing the model prediction from the base value, which is the average model output in training set.

I have around 5,000 observations along with 70 features. The performance of DeepExplainer is quite satisfactory. And my code is:

```
model0 = load_model(model_p+'health0.h5')

background = healthScaler.transform(train[healthFeatures])
e = shap.DeepExplainer(model0, background)
shap_values = e.shap_values(healthScaler.transform(test[healthFeatures]))

test2 = test[healthFeatures].copy()
test2[healthFeatures] = healthScaler.transform(test[healthFeatures])

shap.force_plot(e.expected_value[0], shap_values[0][947,:], test2.iloc[947,:])
```

And the plot is the following:
[image]

Here the base value is 0.012 (can also be seen through **e.expected_value[0]**) and very close to the output value which is 0.01.

At this point I have some questions:

1) The output value is not identical to the prediction gotten through **model0.predict(test[healthFeatures])[947] = -0.103** How should I assess output value?

2) As can be seen, I am using whole training set as the background to approximate conditional expectations of SHAP values. What is the difference between using random samples from training set and entire set? Is it only related to performance issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: do you know if DeepExplainer is suitable for a MLPClassifier or should I go with KernelExplainer? The second option seems to consume all the RAM available on google colab

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but stil a most common question that will benefit other begginers. To answer (1), the expected and out values will be different. the expected is, as the name suggest, is the avereage over the scores predicted by your model, e.g., if it was probability then it is the average of the probabilties that your model spits. For (2), as long as the backroung values are less then 5k, it wont change much, but if > 5k then your calculations will take days to finish.

See [this](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/explainers/deep/__init__.py) (lines 21-25) for more comprehensive answers.